# No write permissions after copy files from Windows

Tags: macos, network, permission

I have Mac mini (High Sierra 10.13.3) as a server. Server has external HDD formated as Mac OS Extended (Journaled). I'm using a PC (Windows 10, NTFS) for downloading files. When I copy files from my PC to my Mac mini, the Mac mini administrator (me) doesn't have permissions for read/write and I can't open new files.

[image: no permissions]

So I have to add my user and set the right permissions.

[image: corrected permissions]

It is very annoying to do that every time when I copy something new. Do you have some easy solution, how to fix this once for all?

Comment: *How* are you copying the files from your PC to the Mac mini?

Comment: ...and if it is over the network log into the mini with your Mac username and password.

Comment: @Allan: I have LAN sharing via SMB protocol

Comment: @SteveChambers: I'm loging to my MacMini with my Mac username and password.

Comment: Not what protocol, the *procedure* you are using to copy.  Are you connecting to the Windows machine from the Mac or are you on the Windows machine?

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites, pick one & stick to it - https://superuser.com/questions/1297626/macos-no-write-permissions-after-copy-files-from-windows

Comment: @Allan: Im on my PC. I open network, find my MacMini, choose destination directory and copy into it.

Comment: Pls help. I still didn't solve this annoying issue :/